# type trait for function pointer?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I need to conditionally use either `std::abs` or `std::fabs` inside template class, here is relevant code in simplified version:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, std::uint64_t, long double>;
    using check = std::is_integral<type>;

    // ERROR: mismatch in format parameter list
    constexpr auto ptr_abs = check::value ? &std::abs<check::value_type> : &std::fabs;

    // use pointer
    void use_ptr()
    {
        auto x = (*ptr_abs)(-3);
    }
};
```

None of the attempts worked for me, I'm clueless.

```
int main()
{
     C<int> a;
     a.f();

     C<float> b;
     b.f();
}
```

Comment: Can't you like `ptr_abs = &std::abs<T>`?

Comment: @KamilCuk no because `std::abs<double>` resolves to `std::abs(std::complex<t>)`

Comment: Types of second and third argument of a ternary operator must be the same or convertible.

Comment: @DanielLangr ah ok, I guess I'll have to split this one liner into at least 3 lines then :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to work with function pointers? Wouldn't be better to exploit C++ type-safe mechanisms? Such as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, std::uint64_t, long double>;
    static const bool check = std::is_integral_v<type>;

    std::function<type(type)> abs = [](auto arg)
    {
        if constexpr (check) return std::abs(static_cast<long long>(arg));
        else return std::fabs(arg);
    };

    void use()
    {
        auto x = abs(-3);
    }
};
```

This [works for me well](https://godbolt.org/z/t7-i8G). Just note that there is no `std::abs` for unsigned integers, therefore, to avoid ambiguity, I had to choose a particular overload by casting (to `long long` in this example; I don't know what is `Result`).

---

Before C++17, where there is no `if constexpr`, you can achieve the same just with some more typing by using template specializations.

Comment: awesome, I really like your solution! `<Result>` never mind, I'll remove it from my post.

Comment: `Just note that there is no std::abs for unsigned integers` didn't know that, isn't `abs` supposed to return positive number is negative is given? : https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/absolute-value.html

Comment: @metablaster Sure, therefore it does not make any sense to have `std::abs` overloaded for arguments of unsigned types :).

Comment: ah, ok, well that's cheating if you ask me ;)

Comment: I would use regular method, instead of `std::function`.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve the function overload with the type of the pointer:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class C {
public:
    static constexpr T (*ptr_abs)(T) = &std::abs;
    void f() {
        std::cout << typeid(ptr_abs).name() << "\n";
        auto x = (*ptr_abs)(-3);
    }
};

int main()
{
     C<int> a;
     a.f(); // PFiiE
     C<float> b;
     b.f(); // PFffE
     C<double> c;
     c.f(); // PFddE
}
```

Comment: Och, it is, i didn't know. So this will not work for `C<std::complex<double>>` : /

Comment: @KamilCuk it will work, even with abs being a template.

Comment: @KamilCuk nice solution but I need `ptr_abs` to resolve to either `std::uint64_t` or `double` not `T`

Comment: `resolve to either std::uint64_t or double not` `using T2 = std::condition<std::is_integral<T>::value, long long, double>::type` + `T2 (*ptr_abs)(T2)`. I don't think there is `std::abs(std::uint64_t)`

Comment: @KamilCuk ah of course! I was so focused on one thing that I overlooked the other ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've misunderstood your problem, but it seems to me that you could separately define your version of `abs` that behaves as you want and then use it inside other classes

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace my {

template <class T>
auto abs_(T x)
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_unsigned_v<T> ) {
        return static_cast<uintmax_t>(x);
    }
    else if constexpr ( std::is_integral_v<T> ) {
        return static_cast<uintmax_t>(std::abs(static_cast<intmax_t>(x)));
    }
    else {
        return std::fabs(static_cast<long double>(x));
    }  
}

template <class T>
auto abs_(std::complex<T> const& x)
{
    return std::abs(static_cast<std::complex<long double>>(x));
}

}

template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    void use(T x)
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ' ' << x;
        auto a = my::abs_(x);
        std::cout << ' ' << typeid(a).name() << ' ' << a << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    C<int> a;
    a.use(-42);

    C<float> b;
    b.use(-0.1);

    C<long long> c;
    c.use(std::numeric_limits<long long>::min());

    C<size_t> d;
    d.use(-1);

    C<std::complex<double>> e;
    e.use({-1, 1});
}
```

Testable [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Q9msyi).